# Convert int with starting zeros to string to check length

Tags: javascript, integer, tostring

I have an html input type="number" field in an html page. like this:

```
<input type="number">
```

To validate the form I need to check that the length of this field is exactly 3. To do this I convert the number to String and execute the `length()` function.

The problem comes when the number starts with a zero. like `065`

In that case the `toString()` method outputs a `65` with a length of `2`

Do you have any idea on how to get the correct length of the number ?

Comment: Perhaps you should set the input type as string rather than number and covert to number when you really need it as a number.

Comment: @lurker for that reason, I prefer making all my numerical inputs as strings and parsing them later when I need the numbers to make validation easier.

Comment: `console.log("065".toString());` prints `065` only

Comment: how are you retrieving the number at the start?

Comment: I don't see what you want to do? If you want exactly three, and it is less then three, pad it with zeros?

Comment: I don't see the point of using a number input type there because: 1) It is not cross-browser compatible. 2) You still need to convert that number to a string in order to do your stuff. 3) you probably will need later to convert it back to a number, so why not using a generic text input?

Comment: I'm not sure what everyone is confused about with this question. The user types in a number, which is a string. The OP wants to remove the leading zeroes and check to see how many digits the user typed in: `00123` should be valid because `123` is three digits. It's a simple case of stripping the leading zeroes. No need for a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would have to have your input type as text and then use JavaScript to get the length for validation. After that you could convert it to a number using the Number() function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the input type to text and restrict the input with a pattern and maxlength:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this one of two ways:

1. When the user moves focus away from the field, remove the leading zeroes
2. In the validation, remove the leading zeroes then check the length

There is no need to convert to a number.

**Removing leading zeroes when focus is lost:**

```
function truncateNumericInput(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    event.target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (event.target.nodeName != "INPUT" || event.target.type != "number") {
        return;
    }

    var input = event.target,
        value = event.target.value;

    input.value = value.indexOf(".") > -1
        ? value.replace(/^0{2,}/, "0")
        : value.replace(/^0+/, "");
}

if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("blur", truncateNumericInput, true);
} else {
    document.attachEvent("focusout", truncateNumericInput);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67jyg1d9/

**Removing leading zeroes during validation**

```
var regex = /^0+/;
var value = input.value.replace(regex, "");

console.log(value.length <= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="999">
```

this takes care that only number can be entered and only till 999 that's 3 digits at max

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using input type as number. You can build your logic by using overflow and underflow as shown below.

```
<input id="numtest" type="number" min="10" max="20" />

document.getElementById('numtest').validity.rangeOverflow
document.getElementById('numtest').validity.rangeUnderflow
  or 
document.getElementById('numtest').checkValidity();
```

rangeUnderflow: return true if value is less then min

rangeOverflow: return true if value is greater than max value.